# Javascript Fetch API equivalent in Java for Http requests?

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am currently learning about Threads in Java. I wanted to know what the standard protocol would be when making Http Requests in Java that would be similar to the code I have below, which uses Javascript Fetch API and asynchronous programming. For example, if I was using the Fetch API in Javascript to *first* make a **GET** request to grab some data from a REST endpoint that I would later use to make a **POST** request (as seen in the code below), I would need to use a *Callback function* or *Promise* (like below) to **wait** until that *first* request has retrieved its data for the second request to then proceed. Obviously, if I did not use Promises or nest the second Http **POST** in the first Fetch method (**GET**) below, and wrote two separate Fetch API calls (one for **GET**, one for **POST**, sequentially one after other aka top-to-bottom), both calls would "fire-off" simultaneously and the second **POST** request wouldn't have the data it needs to make a successful **POST**.

```js
const myHttpGETandPOSTmethod = () => {

    // First Http request goes here

    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: // Some headers here,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
                console.log(data))

            // Nest the second Http request inside here. It only runs after 1st request completes

            return fetch('http://example.com/movies.json', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: // Some headers here,
                        body: JSON.stringify(body);
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log('Success:', data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
        })
}
```

So then, if I were using something like the **Apache HttpClient** https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html library in Java, would the standard procedure be to "spin-up" another Thread (besides the main thread) to execute the **GET** request and then do a **thread.join()** such that after the first thread completes, then the second request can fire-off its own Thread?

Would I need to use a **Callable** instead of **Runnable** so that I can save the HttpEntity data response of the first **GET** request?

I guess I'm just trying to understand the best way to implement the scenario I posed above regarding an HTTP GET request that is needed to make a subsequent POST request, while both fires asynchronously such that they do **not** block the main thread.

You can make a basic **GET** request using the apache Http Library as such (**POST** is also very similar):

```js
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://targethost/homepage");
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

try {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();

    // Save the response body to a string
    String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(body);

    EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
} finally {
    response1.close();
}
```

Or am I on the wrong approach here and looking at this incorrectly? I believe the Http library in Apache offers both synchronous and asynchronous Http calls? or should I be using a newer library for Http in Java?